# Pass parameter to Servlet on page load

Tags: jsp, servlets, parameters, load, parameter-passing

I'm using a Servlet to load a PDF file from my DB and disply it on an HTML `<object>`on the page. 
My page contains a download button that pass a parameter to a servlet and download another file from my DB. My PDF Servlet is working fine, but isn't getting the parameter from my JSP page to load the file on the page.
 For Example: I have a `SELECT` query on my PDF Servlet to get the correct PDF file: `select pdf from pdf where id = ?`, the problem is that the servlet can't get the parameter from the page and put it in my `?` query. But if I do it manually like `select pdf from pdf where id = 1`, than my page loads the PDF file. 
This is my index.jsp:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 06/08/2015, 16:14:51
    Author     : Henrique
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <h1>Teste Download XML</h1>
        <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/downloadDB">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=request.getParameter("id")%>" />
            <button type="submit">Download</button>
        </form>

        <object data="pdf" type="application/pdf" width="1000" height="1000"/> 
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my DisplayPDF Servlet doGet method:

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int uploadId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database

        try {
            // connects to the database
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            // queries the database
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM xmlNFe WHERE xml_id = ?";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, uploadId);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            if (result.next()) {
                Blob blob = result.getBlob("xml_pdf");
                InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                String fileName = result.getString("xml_chnfe");
                int fileLength = inputStream.available();

                System.out.println("fileLength = " + fileLength);

                ServletContext context = getServletContext();

                // sets MIME type for the file download
                String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    mimeType = "application/pdf";
                }

                response.setContentType(mimeType);
                response.setContentLength(fileLength);
                String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                String headerValue = String.format("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
                response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
                OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DisplayPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And this is my other servlet that is called when the user clicks the Download button:

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // get upload id from URL's parameters
        int uploadId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database

        try {
            // connects to the database
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            // queries the database
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM xmlNFe WHERE xml_id = ?";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, uploadId);

            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                // gets file name and file blob data
                String fileName = result.getString("xml_chnfe");
                Blob blob = result.getBlob("xml_xml");
                InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                int fileLength = inputStream.available();

                System.out.println("fileLength = " + fileLength);

                ServletContext context = getServletContext();

                // sets MIME type for the file download
                String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                }

                // set content properties and header attributes for the response
                response.setContentType(mimeType);
                response.setContentLength(fileLength);
                String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName + ".xml");
                response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                // writes the file to the client
                OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                outStream.close();
            } else {
                // no file found
                // response.getWriter().print("File not found for the id: " + uploadId);  
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response.getWriter().print("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response.getWriter().print("IO Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BDFileDownloadServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need more details, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution!
The thing was it was missing the parameter in the PDF servlet call. The solution was changing
`<object data="pdf" type="application/pdf" width="1000" height="1000"/>`
By
`<object data="pdf?id=<=%request.getParameter("id")%>" type="application/pdf" width="1000" height="1000"/>`